# How to properly train batch-wise in VowpalWabbit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, training-data, vowpalwabbit, convergence

We are trying to train a VowpalWabbit (VW) model in an online-fashion. However, due to our system architecture and needs to scale, we have to train batch-wise and cannot do an online-update each time we predict.

My question is, what is the best way to approach this in regards of convergence. Is there maybe a special mode to run VW for this?

What we currently do:

Init Model:
`--cb_explore_adf -q UA -q UU --quiet --save_resume --bag 10 --epsilon 0.1`

Inference (separately):

1. Load vw model
2. Predict -> action-distribution
3. Sample randomly from action-distribution and playout

Training (separately)(triggered periodically):

1. Load model
2. Load training data (action, context, reward) (reward=1.0 if article_clicked else 0) (from-time=last-train-time, end-time=current-time)
3. Update model individually (always using probability 1.0). Example training instance:

```
    shared |User device=device-1 
    |Action ad=article-1 
    1:0:1 |Action ad=article-2 
    |Action ad=article-3 
    |Action ad=article-4
```

4. Store vw model

Is there something wrong with this approach? I suspect that providing the training data in batches and doing a per-instance update on these is not what the exploration algorithm expects. In offline experiments batch-wise training seems often slightly worse vs. non-batch training.

**EDIT**
To the question which probability to use when learning, we tested the usage of the probability generated by the model during prediction and always using 1.0 (on a Toy game, batch_size=500):

Using probability of prediction for training:
[image: Toy game, batch_size=500, using probability of prediction for training]

Always using 1.0:
[image: Toy game, batch_size=500, using probability of 1.0 always for training]

**EDIT 2**

Adding another graphic, comparing Vowpal Wabbit models using probability of prediction vs always using probability of 1.0 for training. Top-Graph: X-Axis: Number of samples, Y-Axis: total CTR (click-through-rate basically the total average reward). Bottom-Graph: Histogram of actions (1-3) chosen by the different algorithms.
[image]

The Chart is comparing 8 Vowpal Wabbit models. 4 models which always use 1.0 for the training as probability. 4 models use the probability of prediction. Always using 1.0 seems to perform consistently better.

*Additional Explanation for Graphics:*

The models are competing in a Toy Problem for contextual algorithms, where a context is presented (6 different pseudo device types) with three possible actions (also called variant). The CTRs look as follow:

```py
    problem_definition = {
                "device-1": {"variant-1": 0.05, "variant-2": 0.06, "variant-3": 0.04},  # 2
                "device-2": {"variant-1": 0.08, "variant-2": 0.07, "variant-3": 0.05},  # 1
                "device-3": {"variant-1": 0.01, "variant-2": 0.04, "variant-3": 0.09},  # 3
                "device-4": {"variant-1": 0.04, "variant-2": 0.04, "variant-3": 0.045},  # 3
                "device-5": {"variant-1": 0.09, "variant-2": 0.01, "variant-3": 0.07},  # 1
                "device-6": {"variant-1": 0.03, "variant-2": 0.09, "variant-3": 0.04}  # 2
            }
```

The toy-game's simulation-logic:

```py
    def simulate(self, device, variant):
        assert variant in self.action_space()
        ctr = self.problem_definition[device][variant]

        if random.random() < ctr:
            reward = 1.0
        else:
            reward = 0.0
        
        return reward
```

The goal of the toy game is to choose the action with the highest CTR given the device type.

Example of how a training example for Vowpal Wabbit is formatted:

```
shared |User device=device-4
|Action ad=variant-1
|Action ad=variant-2
0:0.0:1.00 |Action ad=variant-3
```

And another one, not using static 1.0 probability:

```
shared |User device=device-1
|Action ad=variant-1
0:0.0:0.93 |Action ad=variant-2
|Action ad=variant-3
```

All models were initialized the same:

```
--cb_explore_adf -q UA -q UU --quiet --save_resume --epsilon 0.100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely train in batches from logged data, however the probability you are using during training is incorrect.

When you do inference you will get a list of probabilities which you must sample from to determine which action to play. This action will have some cost associated with it.

Then when training for each of these logged predictions and outcomes you must use the cost this played action received and importantly the probability with which this action was chosen. This is the value in the list of probabilities that corresponded to this action.

Comment: I added an edit to the original question. On a toy game, I used the probability of the sampled action during inference for training and the performance was always worse. When passing these instances to the model, do I have to give them as a batch? Currently I do one at a time: ```vw.learn(self._format(context, (action, cost, probability)))``` with the probability of the sampled action during inference.

Comment: Passing them one at a time should work just fine. I would suggest playing around with the sample size (try more training samples) especially if the reward is just 0/1

Comment: Sorry the graph is deceiving It wasn't just 500 training instances but 50000 (batch-size is 500). The X-Axis is labeled incorrectly (divided by 100 because I was only plotting every 100 steps) @olgavrou

Comment: @AlexanderBartl in the plot is that accumulated reward over time or is it the individual reward for each event? keep in mind that when exploration is enabled, here epsilon is set to 0.1, that means that exploitation is happening 90% of the time and exploration is happening 10% of the time, so it is likely that even on a learned model you won't get the best immediate reward ~10% of the time

Comment: @olgavrou The blue line is the CTR that the model's policy would produce. If you look at the lowest lows, highest highs and the general average, using 1.0 as a static probability seems to generate a more consistent good outcome. Both use epsilon 0.1 so it should not affect the average so much. I hope I find some time soon to create more graphics.

Comment: @olgavrou edited the original post with another graphic.